# Prediction Model: Logistic regression model, a popular model for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make a prediction based on the winning party. The column that I have selected is the candidate party and the vote of the candidate as in the dataset. My code is as follow:-

```
# Loading and cleaning dataset
df4 = pd.read_csv('Election-Results-2018 - Parlimen_Results_By_Candidate.csv')
df4['Votes for Candidate'] = df4['Votes for Candidate'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
df4['Total Votes Cast'] = df4['Total Votes Cast'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
df4['% of total Votes'] = df4['% of total Votes'].str.replace('%','').astype(float)

# Step 1 - import the model 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Step 2 - Define your training data
columns = ['Candidate Party', 'Votes for Candidate']

# Step 3 - create training dataset
X = df[columns]
y = df['New Results']*
```

After running these codes, I receive an error as follow:-

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Candidate Party', 'Votes for Candidate'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I am a beginner in machine learning and hope to get assistance and guidance from anybody. TQ

Comment: You can format code using back ticks. On one line, write " \```python " without the quotation marks. On the next lines write your code. After that write three more back ticks: " \``` "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple mistake, you used incorrect name `df` instead of `df4`, this should work:

```
df4 = pd.read_csv('Election-Results-2018 - Parlimen_Results_By_Candidate.csv')
df4['Votes for Candidate'] = df4['Votes for Candidate'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
df4['Total Votes Cast'] = df4['Total Votes Cast'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
df4['% of total Votes'] = df4['% of total Votes'].str.replace('%','').astype(float)

# Step 1 - import the model 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Step 2 - Define your training data
columns = ['Candidate Party', 'Votes for Candidate']

# Step 3 - create training dataset
X = df4[columns]
y = df4['New Results']
```

Comment: Thank you sir, my bad that overlook on the df and df4.

Comment: Dear sir, I have update the codes and my report can be view at https://zzahir1978.github.io/projects/GE14.html. Please feels free to leave me a comments should you find that there are improvement can be done in the reports. I am a beginner in python data analyst and machine learning. Appreciate for your kind guidance. TQ

Comment: Except you are not splitting data to train and test part (train_test_split) I see no problems, you can now accept the answer and if you have further problems in future ask a new question.

Comment: Well noted sir. TQ